# Azure B2C Dynamics Claims Mapping

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-ad-b2c, dynamics-crm-portals

I'm following Microsoft's guidance to enable Dynamics Portal access via Azure AD B2C.  Basics are up and running and working well.  I'm using a "Sign-In" Policy.  However, I'm having trouble with the claims mapping functionality.

I've configured the following site settings per the instructions in the document linked below.

Authentication/OpenIdConnect/B2C/RegistrationClaimsMapping
Authentication/OpenIdConnect/B2C/LoginClaimsMapping

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/azure-ad-b2c#claims-mapping

However, the mapped Dynamics attribute values are never (initial registration/contact creation, or subsequent logins) updated with values from Azure AD B2C, as expected based on this configuration.

An example of the Site Setting Value that I've tried:
address1_city=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/city

If I look at the JWT form data id_token after authentication, I see the values from B2C in the payload.

Is there an additional step not covered in the document to enable this functionality?  Is this currently broken/not yet supported?  Are my expectations of how this should be working (Dynamics attributes values updated based on B2C values) incorrect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the claim name the same as what is being returned within your ID Token. For example address1_city=city. Unless the Partner ClaimType within your B2C Policy is explicitly set to "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/city".

Comment: The claim name that I see in the id_token is "city".  I've tried with that mapping as well, with the same result: address1_city=city

Comment: Have you tried a mapping to an attribute in Dynamics thats not a Logical Attribute like surname?

Comment: I've tried jobtitle=jobTitle & lastname=surname, with the same, unsuccessful, result